# How to check if the Array date is in specific pattern

Tags: powershell

I am able to check a single date using below working code.

```
$date    = "01/APR/2010:10:10:10"
$format  = 'dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss'
    
if(![datetime]::TryParseexact($date,$format,[system.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo]::InvariantInfo,[system.Globalization.DateTimeStyles]::None, [ref]$result ))
{
    echo "Date format failed" 
}
```

But I am unable to verify if the dates are in an array, like this

`$date = @("01/APR/2010:10:10:10","01/MAY/2010:10:10:10")`

Comment: Your code is missing the declaration for the `$result` variable, which should be a DateTime object

Answer (score 0):

You just need to iterate through dates one by one.

```
$dates = @("01/APR/2010:10:10:10","01/MAY/2010:10:10:10")
foreach ($date in $dates) {
   # add verification code here
}
```

Comment: Thanks Igor , in that case my csv file has around 3 crore record, it may affect performance, am correct?